# Fastlane is running version 2.114 instead of 2.110 after a reinstall

Tags: rubygems, fastlane

After uninstalling/reinstalling an older version of Fastlane, it still appears to be running the latest version.

I recently updated Fastlane to version 2.114, but when I ran my ionic ios build script, it failed on the get_provisioning_profile step. It had worked fine just before I ran the update.

I uninstalled it using gem uninstall fastlane, then reinstalled it using gem install fastlane -v 2.110.0, gem list fastlane showed only version 2.110.0.

Then I ran the script again and the box in the get_provisioning_profile step still showed version 2.114.0 and the step failed with the same error.

Does anyone know how to make Fastlane use version 2.110.0, instead of the latest version?

To uninstall/reinstall Fastlane:

```
gem uninstall fastlane
gem install fastlane -v 2.110.0
```

The result of gem list fastlane:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

commander-fastlane (4.4.6)
fastlane (2.110.0)
```

Expected result:

```
+-------------------------------------+--------------------------+
|                    Summary for sigh 2.110.0                    |
+-------------------------------------+--------------------------+
```

and the Fastlane script to work successfully as before.

Actual result:

An example of one of the Fastlane boxes showing v2.114:

```
+-------------------------------------+--------------------------+
|                    Summary for sigh 2.114.0                    |
+-------------------------------------+--------------------------+
```

The Fastlane error messages:

```
[13:47:24]: No existing profiles found, that match the certificates you have installed locally! Creating a new provisioning profile for you

[13:47:25]: No certificates for filter: Certificate ID: '433NN4XZ66' 

[13:47:25]: Could not find a matching code signing identity for type 'AdHoc'. It is recommended to use match to manage code signing for you, more information on https://codesigning.guide. If you don't want to do so, you can also use cert to generate a new one: https://fastlane.tools/cert
```

[Edit: 2019-01-24]

fastlane env output (it says v2.112.0, because this is after I've tried various other ideas, including installing another version, but still have the problem):

```
### Stack

| Key                         | Value                                       |
| --------------------------- | ------------------------------------------- |
| OS                          | 10.14.2                                     |
| Ruby                        | 2.5.1                                       |
| Bundler?                    | false                                       |
| Git                         | git version 2.18.0                          |
| Installation Source         | ~/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/fastlane        |
| Host                        | Mac OS X 10.14.2 (18C54)                    |
| Ruby Lib Dir                | ~/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib                 |
| OpenSSL Version             | OpenSSL 1.0.2p  14 Aug 2018                 |
| Is contained                | false                                       |
| Is homebrew                 | false                                       |
| Is installed via Fabric.app | false                                       |
| Xcode Path                  | /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/ |
| Xcode Version               | 10.1                                        |

### System Locale

| Variable | Value       |   |
| -------- | ----------- | - |
| LANG     | en_GB.UTF-8 | ✅ |
| LC_ALL   |             |   |
| LANGUAGE |             |   |

### fastlane files:

**No Fastfile found**

**No Appfile found**

### fastlane gems

| Gem      | Version | Update-Status      |
| -------- | ------- | ------------------ |
| fastlane | 2.112.0 |  Update available |

### Loaded fastlane plugins:

**No plugins Loaded**
```

Comment: What OS are you using? What does `fastlane -v` return? What command(s) do you run that then execute `sigh`?

Comment: I'm using MacOs Mojave 10.14.2 and fastlane -v shows: fastlane 2.110.0. The command for sigh in the fastfile is: get_certificates(development: true, username: "myusername").

Comment: That is really strange. Please add the output of `fastlane env` to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this on macOS catalina

```
sudo gem install fastlane --version {version} -n /usr/local/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

> fastlane_version "2.110.0"

at the beginning of Fastfile

Comment: That can specify only the minimum version of Fastlane required. It cannot be used to ensure that a particular version of Fastlane is used.